# Autofac - How to implement a factory that uses run-time information?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, delegates, autofac

I have a factory that creates message handlers as incoming messages arrive. The message handlers take several dependencies - a configuration object that is selected based on the incoming message, and other infrastructure components.

I'm using Autofac, with delegates, and I am having trouble avoiding coupling my MessageHandlerFactory to specific implementation classes.

Here is the only way I've been able to inject delegates into the factory:

```
// Handler defines a delegate that Autofac turns into a factory method
public class FtpMessageHandler : IFtpMessageHandler {
    public delegate FtpMessageHandler Factory (Configuration configuration);

    public FtpMessageHandler(Configuration configuration,
        S3Facade s3Facade,
        .... other dependencies.....
    )
    ....
}

// In Autofac module..

    // This is how I'd like to register the component, but it does NOT 
    // work - Autofac fails to resolve the delegate
    builder.RegisterType<FtpMessageHandler>().As<IFtpMessageHandler>();

    // This is what DOES work    
    builder.RegisterType<FtpMessageHandler>();



public class MessageHandlerFactory {
    public FtpMessageHandler.Factory FtpMessageHandlerFactory { get; }
    ...
    public MessageHandlerFactory( FtpMessageHandler.Factory ftpMessageHandlerFactory, ....)

        FtpMessageHandlerFactory = ftpMessageHandlerFactory;
    )

    public IMessageHandler GetMessageHandler(MessageTypeEnum type, Configuration config) {
        if (type == MessageTypeEnum.FTP)
            return FtpMessageHandlerFactory.Invoke(config);
       ....
   )
}
```

So...... this works, after a fashion.

But I am unhappy about having to inject concrete types into the MessageHandlerFactory. For instance, this rules out using decorators on the IMessageHandler without modifying the factory.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Prevent having to inject runtime data into applicatino components. That's [an anti-pattern](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

Comment: Good point. In my current solution, the runtime data is fed into a method after object creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, based on the approach described by Alex Meyer-Gleaves http://alexmg.com/selectively-resolving-services-at-runtime-with-autofac/

```
// New class
public class MessageHandlerMetadata
{
    public FileTransportTypeEnum TransportType { get; set; }
}


// Registration    
        builder.Register(c => new FtpMessageHandler( c.Resolve<IS3Facade>(), c.Resolve<IFtpHelper>()))
            .As<IMessageHandler>()
            .WithMetadata<MessageHandlerMetadata>(m => m.For(am => am.TransportType, FileTransportTypeEnum.FTP));

        ....

        builder.Register(
            c => new MessageHandlerFactory(c.Resolve<IConfigurationProvider>(),
                c.Resolve<IEnumerable<Lazy<IMessageHandler, MessageHandlerMetadata>>>()))
            .As<IMessageHandlerFactory>();


// In the Factory

    public MessageHandlerFactory(
        IEnumerable<Lazy<IMessageHandler, MessageHandlerMetadata>> messageHandlers) { ... }


    private IMessageHandler GetHandlerByConfigurationType(FileTransportTypeEnum fileTransportType,
        DestinationConfiguration configuration)
    {

        var lazy = MessageHandlers.FirstOrDefault(h => h.Metadata.TransportType == fileTransportType);
        if (lazy == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"No handler is registered with File Transport type {fileTransportType}.");
        }
        var handler = lazy.Value;
        handler.Configure(configuration);
        return handler;
```